# Runtime error but project compiles fine - Imports/using missing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, import, using

I am very confused right now. I have VS2008 at my job right now and I have a weird behavior that I have been searching for a while now.

When I compile the project, it works fine, but in runtime I have an error saying object not defined or something like that. The problem is that the imports/using is missing in my class but why does it compile?

In fact, I want to be able to see that error when compiling not when running the webapp.

REEDITED: Here is an example. Lets say i want to use a typed list, I am declaring my object list(of int) for example without having added my imports (system.collection.generic) in the class. then I compile, it works and then I run it, it fails because of the imports missing. is this normal behavior or not?

REREEDITED: I just noticed that the DLL of all my references were not copied in my bin folders even though all of them are set to "Copy local = true". Is it possible that it has to do with our shared directory (all external dlls) being on a network drive (\server\shared). I am really out of ideas on this issue....

Comment: What programming language are you using? This may not be possible in a dynamic language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem was because we were having the classes in the app_data folder

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the current question - why you are getting this error - is that ASP.NET does not show many errors at compile-time. You will need to manually go through the application to verify that all pages work correctly. This is very common with ASP.NET development, due to the nature of the environment.

If you post the real errors (probably should be as another SO question), we can perhaps help you with them.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the dll, etc from bin...
rebuild the whole solution then run
It should run fine...

Comment: I tried to clean solution, remove bin and obj and rebuild a number of times and it is always the same....